# Downloaded Video File Can't be Played in Android

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-videoview

**Problem:**
My downloaded video file can't be played from any player, let alone my app's VideoView, but it plays nicely from the URL into the VideoView.

**What's DONE:**
I'm downloading [a video file](http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4) if it's not in the external storage, otherwise playing it directly from the URL into the VideoView.
The VideoView part of the code is like the following:

```
final VideoView vvPlayer = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vvPlayer);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
mc.setAnchorView(vvPlayer);
vvPlayer.setMediaController(mc);

if (videoFile.exists()) {
    // vvPlayer.setVideoURI(Uri.fromFile(videoFile));  <-- Also Tried :(
    vvPlayer.setVideoPath(videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Toast.makeText(this, "Playing from local ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    vvPlayer.setVideoPath(VIDEO_PATH);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Playing online & caching ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    downloadVideoFile();
}
```

The core-part, i.e., `the doInBackground()` of the `downloadVideoFile()` method's AsyncTask returns the file-content as a string using the following codes:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    URLConnection conn;
    try {
        URL httpFileUrl = new URL(fileUrl);
        conn = httpFileUrl.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Connection opened");
    InputStream inputStream;
    try {
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream(), 4096);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                                 new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    int responseLen = 0;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String responseStr;
    try {
        while ((responseStr = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Log.i(TAG, "Response read: " + responseStr);
            stringBuilder.append(responseStr.trim());
            // ...my progress-bar related codes
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    responseStr = stringBuilder.toString();
    return responseStr;
}
```

After getting the file-content, I've trivially saved those in a file using the codes below:

```
        try {
            if (!APP_DIRECTORY.exists())
                APP_DIRECTORY.mkdirs();
            if (videoFile.createNewFile())
                Log.d(TAG, "Vide-file newly created");

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);
            fos.write(fileContent.getBytes());
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception for new creation of videoFile");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The final result is an 8.81 MB file, which can't be opened as a video file with any video player, let alone my tried VideoView.

May be I'm missing something like **codec**, **encoding** or even simple **file-saving** part?

Comment: No, StringBuilder cannot handle the binary video data. You should not use readLine() which is tuned for textual data. Write the data to your FileOutputStream directly as soon as you get it from the network. Don't aggregate it in memory: a video may contain much more bytes than what your RAM can accommodate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Replace your doInBackground with this:

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    URLConnection conn;
    try {
        URL httpFileUrl = new URL(fileUrl);
        conn = httpFileUrl.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Connection opened");
    InputStream inputStream;
    try {
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpFileUrl.openStream(), 8192);
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.mp4");

byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
output.write(data, 0, count);
}
output.flush();
output.close();
            inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }


    return null;
}


And in onPostExecute,

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        String videoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile.mp4";
        // Now pass this path for playing video.
    }
```

Comment: Isn't there any use of `conn` object initialized at the first section of the method? ... I see you've initialized the `inputStream` using `httpFileUrl.openStream()` directly ...

Comment: conn object can be used to fetch the attributes of the file, example, length of the content and use it to verify downloaded content or show the progress of the file getting downloaded, etc.    int videofilelength = conn.getContentLength();